# Vaadin 8: How to display full-size picture in grid?

Tags: vaadin, vaadin8, vaadin-grid

I am trying to display a list of persons in Vaadin 8 grid, including their photos (JPEGs in byte[]).
However, in the component column (see the code below) only the top of the picture is visible.

```
personsGrid.addComponentColumn(v -> {
    if (v.getPhoto() != null) {
            Image personsPhoto = new Image();
            displayImage(personsPhoto, v.getPhoto());
            return personsPhoto;
    } 
    return new Image("", new ThemeResource("img/no-picture.jpg"));
});
```

Is there a way to show full-size picture in a grid?
How generally make grid rows adjust their heights depending on the content height?

Comment: As far as I'm aware. There's no such functionality for dynamic heights on Grid Rows. You can explicitly set the height of all rows by overriding the underlying CSS. But you can't get them to adjust automatically.

Comment: Thanks @Jay, it looks so. Could you give me any hint about which CSS styles are responsible for the grid row height?

Comment: It's explained in the official Vaadin Docs: https://vaadin.com/docs/v8/framework/components/components-grid.html

Answer (score 3):

As mentioned in the comment under the question, this cannot be achieved dynamically but you can explicitly set the height of the Grid Row using CSS.

Something along the lines of this should give you a steer in the right direction:

**Java:**

```
final Grid<SomeBean> grid = new Grid<>();
grid.addStyleName("custom-grid-style");
```

**CSS:**

```
.custom-grid-style .v-grid-body .v-grid-row .v-grid-cell {
    min-height: 50px;
    line-height: 50px;
}
```

And if you're unsure on where to make the CSS change, you need to add the `@StyleSheet` annotation on either the class you're editing or on the UI. And then the .css file must be in the same package location in your resources folder.

For example:

The class is in the package: `com.example.components`

Then your CSS file would be in: `src/main/resources/com/example/components`